How can I suppress IntelliJ warnings which have no code?
Context
Sometimes, you want to suppress a warning in one specific place, directly in the code, by using annotation @SuppressWarning (I give an example of such cases below).
Problem
I don't know how to find the unique code for the warning, (something like java:S112). It's not written in IntelliJ's warning popup and not suggested in the solutions.
More generally, why do some warnings have a code and some others don't, and how do I suppress warnings that don't seem to have a code?
Example
This is just to illustrate the issue, but it's totally irrelevant to the question.
Consider this mockito code :
@Mock
SomeClass toBeInjected;

@InjectMocks
Service myService;

toBeInjected will be automagically injected into myService. That is standard unit test practice.
IntelliJ and/or Sonarqube fail to understand the subtlety. They think that because I don't access toBeInjected , it's never used and therefore should be deleted.
I want to suppress this warning directly in the code, using the @SuppressWarning annotation.
I want to do it that way because it's not a problem related to my project's environment and I don't want to suppress this kind of warning everywhere. Only here, in this very circumstance, and visible to every other coder.

Please don't tag your titles. See [ask].

You don't need to know the ID of the warning, because IntelliJ IDEA can add the @SuppressWarnings annotation for you. For warnings in the editor:

Put the text caret on the warning
Type Alt+Enter (a menu will appear)
Type the right arrow key on the item that is relevant (which is different for each warning. A submenu will appear)
Select one of the suppress items


Result: a @SuppressWarnings annotation is inserted in the code.
This is how it should work for Java code, with the default settings. For other languages it works similarly, with different ways of suppression.

You are correct and that is the solution. But tis is a blatant case of terrible, TERRIBLE ui! Here's why: In my own IntelliJ, there is no ">" displayed on the right. Instead it's a "..." (the universal symbol for opening another window). And then when I click on those "..." (or when I use the up/down arrow keys to switch between the suggested options) it can either show what's in your screenshot OR a completely different contextul menu  (!). To switch between those two menus there's no button, ONLY LEFT/RIGHT ARROW KEYS. (!!)
